# How to transmit NSObject data in Objective C MultipeerConnectivity framwork

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipeer-connectivity

I am new to Objective C and is working on a iOS mobile app based on `MultipeerConnectivity` network project framework. This framework provides me with send message and receive message methods between devices.

Here I want to send a `MyMessage` NSObject defined by myself as follows through this function to transmit different kinds of data. However, I want to include a `NSMutableArray`, which contains multiple objects of information in a single message object.

```
@interface MyMessage : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray playersInfo;
}
@end
```

I understand that in Objective C we cannot statically allocate interface type like this. Instead we should use a pointer. In this case, however, if I set `playersInfo` as a pointer `NSMutableArray* playersInfo`, then after the object is transmitted to another device, the other device cannot get the data pointed by the `playersInfo`. (I assume `MyMessage` object will be transmitted using only shallow copt so the data in `NSMutableArray* playersInfo` will not be transmitted) Here I am asking how can I achieve a message class that can contain the actually NSObject data.

Comment: Did you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851510/convert-any-data-type-into-nsdata-and-back-again/19851893#19851893

Answer (score 1):

Like any implementation, to send data you need to decompose your primitive, structure or object into a block of data that can be transported across the comms link. Sometimes this is called serialisation (typically when applied to objects)

In iOS, objects can be serialised by using NSKeyedArchive/Unarchive.  So in your example, each of the objects you have stored in your array need to implement the Archive/Unarchive logic by conforming to NSCoding

Then to generate your serialised data (NSData object), you will invoke the archiver on the array object.  NSArray conforms to  the NSCoding protocol.

How deep/shallow you want to go depends on your implementation.  You decide how many of your objects properties you want to encode/decode as part of implementing encodeWithCoder.

I use this pattern to exchange data withpeers, but I also extend it using inheritance - for example I define a class: myMessageBase then inherit that Base class into each of my various Message variants.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I understand that I need to convert my MyMessage object into NSData for transmission. However, here the case is in my MyMessage class I intended to put a NSMutable Array. If I only call Archive on my MyMessage object, will I lose the data pointed by the NSMutable Array pointer in my object? If so, how should I solve it?

Comment: Your implementation of encodeWithCoder will call encode on the NSMutableArray.  Have you read the NSCoding protocol reference?  Its pretty straightforward and a lot of examples if you google.  Ray Wenderlich for example?

Answer (score 0):

```
MultipeerConnectivity framework allows you to send NSData using MCSession API . convert your NSArray to NSData then send
```

[self.session sendData:messageData toPeers:self.session.connectedPeers withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable error:&error];

convert NSData to NSArray

NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]

convert NSArray to NSData

NSString *error;
NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:array format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

Comment: Thanks. Yes I understand that I need to convert my MyMessage object into NSData for transmission. However, here the case is in my MyMessage class I intended to put a NSMutable Array. If I only call Archive on my MyMessage object, will I lose the data pointed by the NSMutable Array pointer in my object? If so, how should I solve it?