# Convert NSValue to NSData and back again, with the correct type

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsdata, nsvalue

I would like to be able to convert an objective-c object, such as an `NSArray` or `UIImage` into an `NSData` object, which I can then use to write to disk. I first converted them to an `NSValue`, which I then planned on converting to `NSData`.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447380/how-to-convert-nsvalue-to-nsdata-and-back) provided part of the answer, but as they were working with `NSNumber`, they didn't really have a need to convert it back to `NSValue`.

I have seen other questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851510/convert-any-data-type-into-nsdata-and-back-again) that relies on `NSKeyedArchiver`, but I would like to steer away from this due to the vast size inflation that occurs.

Therefore my code at the moment for encoding an `NSData` object from an `NSValue`, from the first question, is as follows:

```
+(NSData*) dataWithValue:(NSValue*)value {

    NSUInteger size;

    const char* encoding = [value objCType];
    NSGetSizeAndAlignment(encoding, &size, NULL);

    void* ptr = malloc(size);
    [value getValue:ptr];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:ptr length:size];
    free(ptr);

    return data;
}
```

My question is how would I go about decoding an `NSData` object that has been encoded in this manner and get back the original `objCType` from the `NSValue`?

I would assume I would be using something along these lines

```
[NSValue valueWithBytes:[data bytes] objCType:typeHere];
```

How would I get back the type information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSKeyedArchiver` to save the items and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to restore the object. The object must conform to `NSCoding` and in the case of a collection all contained items must also conform to `NSCoding`.

See the Apple documentation of [NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/index.html) and [NSCoder](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach will only work for primitive types (int, float, structs without pointers, ...) inside your NSValue. Otherwise you will only get the meaningless pointer value but not the actual data in your NSData object.

To also pass the actual type string along you would have to figure out a way to get this inside your NSData object as well. Not impossible, but it will not solve your actual problem.

Using a keyed archiver as zaph suggests is much better.